# What is the correct way to pass an integer through prepared statement

Tags: java, android, prepared-statement

I'm trying to pass two invoice numbers as a range from edittext and find the top numbers of it from sql database. however, the return always shows wrong value. is there something wrong with my prepared statement. my database is saved as nvarchar.

```
        EditText InvoiceS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InvoiceStartTxt);
        InvoiceS.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        InvoiceStart = InvoiceS.getText().toString();
        int intInvoiceS = Integer.parseInt(InvoiceStart);

        EditText InvoiceE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InvoiceEndTxt);
        InvoiceE.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        InvoiceEnd = InvoiceE.getText().toString();
        int intInvoiceE = Integer.parseInt(InvoiceEnd);

        Statement statement = null;
        try{

            String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceNo FROM Android_TrackingNo WHERE InvoiceNo >= ? AND InvoiceNo <= ?";
            PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement1.setString(1,InvoiceStart);
            statement1.setString(2,InvoiceEnd);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement1.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()){
                InvoiceNo.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You are using `setString`

Comment: yes i did pass setInt with value intInvoiceS and intInvoiceE but the result still shows random number, or wrong number.

Comment: can you make a logcat what is the value get from the `intInvoiceE`

Comment: im sorry i dont really understand on how to use logcat. however, i did set back the int into string on the screen, and it did shows a correct value.

Comment: can you make a toast and share here